# Conditional formatting schema workbench

Tags: conditional-statements, string-formatting, pentaho, olap-cube, mondrian

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to a measure of a Mondrian cube in Pentaho schema workbench, but it doesn't work. I'm using this `string_format` expression:

```
Iif(([Measures].[por_cump_tarjeta]<

80),'|#0.00%|style=red|arrow=down',Iif(([Measures].[por_cump_tarjeta]>
80),'|#0.00%|style=yellow|arrow=blank','|#0.00%|style=green|arrow=up'))
```

What is the correct expression?

Answer (score 0):

The FORMAT_STRING attribute set in the schema is not binding. It's up to the client to determine whether to use it or not.

Where are you running the query? Pentaho Analyzer uses format_string to format the results, so does jPivot; but not PRD nor CDA. In those cases you will need to define the format string as a calculated member, return it on the query and use it to format the value on the front end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I defined the format in the "formula | formulaElement" field of a calculated member. Then I want to display it in Saiku or Jpivot. When I drag the field to create the report in Sayku only the corresponding color is displayed but the value does not appear